# How to display chm file inside a wpf window?

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, chm

For a special reason, I am experimenting to create a small WPF application to just open chm file. I would like the wpf application opens, it displays the chm file in the main window. Can someone show me some code how to do it?

Comment: any reason not using a mk:@MSITStore protocol and a webbrowser control? Are you going to display an index/TOC pane?